# How to make an excel script that extracts text between parenthesis in an entire column?

Tags: excel, parsing, search, formula

So I've never really done anything with excel formulas/scripts in my life. Now I'm finally having a need to. Doing some research I found a formula that can extract numbers between parenthesis in a certain cell.

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("(",A2)+1,SEARCH(")",A2)-SEARCH("(",A2)-1)+0
```

Now my question is, without using python, is it possible to make/edit this formula so it will parse through all of column A, then print the totals separately? I would be open to using VBA and creating a macro button however. I've just never coded VBA. Don't have access to python where I'm at so has to be all done within excel.

Thanks for any help, tips, or explanations! I am very interested in learning how it works.

Comment: Without using VBA (or python) I doubt it, but you could achieve what you want with a helper column in excel. If you put this in D2 for example (assuming column D is empty), and [drag the fill handle down](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218) you would get all your numbers in one column. Then you could apply a `Sum` formula to that column to get your totals.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A2:A100,SEARCH("(",A2:A100)+1,SEARCH(")",A2:A100)-SEARCH("(",A2:A100)-1)))`

Comment: @Plutian Would a VBA macro within excel work? I've never written in VB. Where I'm at we can't use python or I would opt for that so I need something easy to use within excel to extract the data periodically.

Comment: @ScottCraner Now how could I get that to run then print the values that it extracts? I see when I input it into an empty cell and press the function it shows them in an array. Thank you!

Comment: You do what @Plutian stated, you will need to fill the formula down the column.

Comment: In the researchded "extract numbers" formula, does the `+0` part needed ? (I mean do you need to add a zero after the extracted value?)